# Connecting a multi-PSU server on different lines with different earthing

Tags: mains, grounding, ups

I am currently preparing to set up a new server which has two PSUs (for supply redundancy). Of course it would be logical to connect them to different sources, but the situation I'm dealing with sounds somewhat concerning to me, even though it might not be.

The situation is as follows (both lines 240V):

- Line A: Neutral and ground joined in the breaker box, marked as TN-C (to be connected via UPS)
- Line B: Ground not connected to the breaker box, but just between a few outlets (older installation with a few newer outlets), though it might be connected properly in the near future

Despite the PSUs being completely separate, the earths would be connected through the enclosure one way or another.

**Is connecting earths on entirely different lines (on a server especially) a terrible idea?**

If earthing is a concern on the currently disconnected earth on line B, should I connect the earth on that to Line A?

And if this setup is a bad idea, how about connecting both PSUs on line A, but only 1 through the UPS?

Comment: Can you measure any voltage difference between your grounds? If yes, can you measure any current between them?

Comment: @winny There appears to be a 0.14V difference between them. I have a clamp multimeter so I don't know how I could measure current I'm afraid.

Comment: Set your multimeter to current measurement by turning the selector and move one of the probes to the other outlet marked “A”. My guess is negligible current. You will end up tieing your two grounds together via your redundant PSUs, so the current will flow there.

Comment: I mean the multimeter only supports amperate measurement by clamps, there is no extra outlets. I'll try to dig up my older one and see what comes up.

Comment: Any crap DMM which can do AC current via built in shunt (10 € DMM) should do.

Comment: @winny there does not appear to be any current between them. Though in that case I guess it would probably be better to make a separate ground connection between outlets that doesn't go through a bunch of expensive computer parts.

Comment: Yes, that would be even better. If it was mine, I would not worry about it. It may be illegal in your country, but I don’t see any technical problem.